# Handling laptops with docking stations on XFCE

Tags: lightdm, xfce, radeon, 14.10

Anyone here running a setup in which they use a laptop + docking station setup for XFCE? At work, I plug/unplug from multi-monitor setups all the time and on unity I didnt have an issue (Radeon driver). Now when I switched over to XFCE, Lightdm greeter puts the login display on my closed laptop on the dock. This also happens when 2 monitors are plugged in and the laptop is closed but NOT docked.

I can type and login and once XFCE is loaded it seems to work OK, but it would be nice to have the login screen placed on ANY monitor that isnt the built-in, closed laptop display.

Perhaps this is more of an issue with Lightdm rather than XFCE, however my setup worked great back on Unity. I suppose I could work with this as-is but it seems like I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but maybe helps someone

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
```

Edit/create field

```
active-monitor = Monitor to display greeter window (name or number). Use #cursor value to display greeter at monitor with cursor.
```